# Буква Й в заимствованных словах

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать: "Плейер" или "плеер", "фейерверк" или "феерверк"? В каких случаях Й выпадает, а в каких — нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Полном орфографическом словаре под ред. Лопатина единственно возможны **плеер** и **фейерверк** соответственно. Слово *фейерверк* в русский пришло из немецкого от Feuerwerk еще во времена Петра I. Видимо, произнесли прямо по буквам (как, например, Дидро долго звали Дидеротом). У слова **плеер** английские корни. Говорить, в каких случаях в заимствованных словах Й выпадает, а в каких нет, невозможно: заимствования происходят из разных языков, по-разному же и наш язык их принимает. Таким словам нужно время для адаптации. Часто бывает так, что какое-то время существуют параллельные варианты одного и того же слова. Так, в Большом толковом словаре есть ПЛЕЙЕР; ПЛЭЙЕР, -а; м. [англ. player] - кассетный проигрыватель небольшого размера, снабжённый наушниками. Потом нормативным признается единственный вариант, а остальные уходят в историю.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала. В подобных случаях орфография - предмет для принятия исключительно субъективных решений, поэтому рассуждать об объективных причинах разнобоя в написании я бы не стал.

У Лопатина плеер и ещё несколько подобных слов даётся как новация, которая, впрочем,   закрепляет написание, сложившееся вопреки действовавшим на тот момент правилам.

Полностью предложение орфографической комиссии звучит так:
*Писать без буквы Й перед Е нарицательные имена существительные с компонентом ЕР: конвеер, стаер.*
Судя по "фейерверку", это предложение надо трактовать так, что -ер для применения этого правила должно быть в конце слова.
С другой стороны статус этих предложений не очень понятен. "Юридически" они не были приняты РАН, поэтому использоать их можно с только с оговорками.